# Refreshing leaflet marker cluster data, not the whole page

Tags: leaflet, setinterval, geojson, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to load my leaflet markercluster data in every one minute. For that I was using pythonscript which generates a geojson file in every minutes. Then i created marker cluster and tried to load that in every minutes by using  setInterval. While trying that, it appears like the new geojson appends to the previous one, But i just want to show the latest one.

[The result i have got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igk6E.jpg)

The code i using is...

```
 setInterval(function() {
$.getJSON("gdf1000_rand_tallinn_auto_try.geojson",function(data){

var tallinn_data = L.geoJson(data,{
  pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
    var marker = L.marker(latlng);
    marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.lat);
    return marker;
  }
});
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
clusters.addLayer(tallinn_data);
map.addLayer(clusters);
  });
   }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is what you described, then you need a conditional statement which checks if the layer has already existed or not.

Please see below the example of a code solving this problem:

```
var geojson = L.geoJSON;

$.getJSON("grid_points", function(data) {
   if (map.hasLayer(geojson)){
         map.removeLayer(geojson); 
            }
   geojson=L.geoJSON(data, {
           style: positium_style
            })
  map.addLayer(geojson);
});
```